# Find `MenuItem` by id `lookup`?

Tags: javafx, clojure, javafx-8, fxml

It seems to not be possible to find `MenuItem`s using `Parent#lookup` because they're items, not children - is this correct? Is there another way to find one by id without writing a complete new search algorithm?

Since I'm using Clojure, not Java, using a controller class is not an option.

Comment: Indeed, `MenuItem`s are not `Node`s, so they are not part of the scene graph. (And `lookup(...)` returns a `Node`, so it cannot return a menu item.) Does using Clojure really preclude you from using controllers? To my mind, that would mean you simply couldn't use Clojure with FXML: using lookups for everything is pretty fragile. (I guess another option would be to use an `fx:id` and get the menu item from the `FXMLLoader`'s [namespace](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/fxml/FXMLLoader.html#getNamespace--).)

Comment: Well, it would be possible to use a Controller class, but it's quite "ugly" and makes boilerplate and ahead-of-time compilation necessary.I'll see if I can do anything with the `FXMLLoader#getNamespace`.

Comment: For now I've made a zipper to traverse the scene graph looking for the id. It's not perfect, but it works.